# Android phone dialer home location

Tags: settings, apk, geolocation

I remember from my HTC HD2 running Cyanogenmod 10.1 a "home location" indicator. It shows the area name of the caller's landline if somebody is calling. The default phone dialer app on my Newman N2 phone running Android 4.1.1 displays a home location in Chinese, instead of my native language (which is Dutch). My settings and stuff are Dutch (so is the rest of the dialer).

The setting can be enabled/disabled here:
Settings -> Call Settings -> "Display Home Location".
(I think it's not available on every Android ROM)

I want that home location indicator to be Dutch. I tried to decompile /system/app/Phone.apk, TelephonyProvider.apk and NetworkLocation.apk, so I could change the Chinese language to Dutch. Then I searched through all of the xml files, but with no result finding the Chinese letters.

To decompile the apks, I used the following tutorial:
http://venomvendor.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-view-source-code-of-android-apk.html

Does anybody know where that home location data is available so I can change it?